# All imports related to Java cannot be found nor imported

Tags: java, intellij-idea

all I've recently updated my IntelliJ and uninstalled the old one, the projects were kept and that's fine. All of my project libraries related to Java are found to be errors. I have no idea what to do everything related to java.something isn't found

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Look at your project settings, make sure you have correctly configured a JDK. Sometimes, "File / Invalidate Caches and Restart" may help.

Comment: Also sometimes IntelliJ gets confused for some reason (when I open someone else's project for example) and I have to go to Project -> Modules and mark `src` as the source folder (the one in blue).

Comment: Restart would help here. I faced this issue a lot recently after updating to latest, and I still do currently.

Comment: Thanks, guys I solved the problem.